# What programing languages does Memgraph support?

Tags: python, java, php, c++, memgraphdb

From which programming languages can I connect to Memgraph? Which protocol is used? I know that Python is for sure supported since there is [GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy) (a fully open-source Python library). What about other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you want to query Memgraph programmatically, you can do so using the [Bolt protocol](https://7687.org/). The Bolt protocol was designed for efficient communication with graph databases and Memgraph supports versions 1 and 4 of the protocol. You can use the Bolt protocol drivers for the following programming languages:

- [Python](https://github.com/memgraph/pymgclient)
- [C/C++](https://github.com/memgraph/mgclient)
- [Rust](https://github.com/memgraph/rsmgclient)
- [Node.js](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver)
- [C#](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver)
- [Go](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver)
- [Haskell](https://github.com/zmactep/hasbolt)
- [Java](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver)
- [JavaScript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver)
- [PHP](https://github.com/neo4j-php/Bolt)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j)